# How to apply a predefined function to entire dataframe without grouping

Tags: pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I am using pandas to get some summary reporting on percentage difference comparing with `new_conversions` vs. `old_conversions`

input table: `df`

| version | device | old_conversions | new_conversions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01 | mobile | 120 | 125 |
| 2021-01 | desktop | 80 | 85 |
| 2021-02 | mobile | 130 | 135 |
| 2021-02 | desktop | 70 | 75 |

Original add function:

```
def agg(x):
    d = {}
    d['conversion_diff'] = round((x['new_conversions'].sum() - x['old_conversions'].sum())/ x['old_conversions'].sum(), 3)

    return pd.Series(d, index=['conversion_diff'])
```

And if I want to get it group by 'device' level, the following script works:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['device']).apply(agg))
```

However, if I did something similarly as an overall level, the following does not work:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.apply(agg))
```

With error message:
**KeyError: 'new_conversions'**

How can I change the script to get it applied to overall level without any groupby?

Desired output for `df2`:

| conversion_diff |
| --- |
| 0.05 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you expect?

```
conv = round((df['new_conversions'].sum() - df['old_conversions'].sum())
             / df['old_conversions'].sum(), 3)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'conversion_diff': [conv]}, index=['All')

out = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

```
>>> out
         conversion_diff
desktop         0.066667
mobile          0.040000
All             0.050000
```

Comment: Thanks I guess for ```df2``` we just need one line of output, also updated the question on that part.

Comment: @CrubalChenxiLi. I updated my answer too. Now it should be right :). You don't need a function for that but If you want a function, it's possible.

Comment: Thanks! That works. Ideally like it by 'device' level as well as an overall; but I imagine could add the following part besides the ```agg``` function too.